What is the JSON syntax to reference a different SharePoint online column from the current field?
I am trying to use the value in the "Product" column as the friendly URL for my "Dummy Link" column which is a long URL. Below is the "Dummy Link" column JSON formatting.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "@currentField",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "txtContent": "[$Product]"
}

The "Dummy Link" is now blank in the SharePoint List.  I tried using [!Product] (still blank in the list) and just [Product] (appeared as [Product] in the list).  What am I missing to make SharePoint recognize the other column?

What is the column/data type of "Product" and "Dummy Link" columns?

Thanks!  "Producct" is a single line of text, while "Dummy Link" is multiple lines of text.

I just tried using the JSON you provided and it is working fine for me.
Make sure:

You are using correct internal name of your "Product" column in JSON. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?.

Your "Product" column is visible in the SharePoint list view --> This is required in order to read values from Product column in the JSON: Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library.


Workaround for #2: If you don't want to show "Product" column in list view, you can try applying "sorting" (or "filtering") based on Product column in list view and then hide Product column from list view.
JSON I used:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "@currentField",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "txtContent": "[$Product]",
  "style": {
    "margin-left": "10px"
  }
}

Output:


I looked up the internal name for "Product", and it was "Product_x0020_Name".  I had changed it to "Product" and did not realize that the internal name had not changed.  Thank you so much!
